# Configure Shared Website Hosting for IIS

Tags: iis-7, port, shared-hosting, website-hosting

I have a server that running IIS7 and DNS server.
I have 2 domains:

```
www.mydomain1.com
www.mydomain2.com
```

I want to visitors from internet coming without port of this sites. What may i do for this?

Comment: Just configure each site in IIS to serve its hostname only.

Comment: what about port configuration?

Comment: Make them both use port 80.

Comment: upps. i don't know that. it was so simple and my question like stupidly now. Ofcourse; thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to set up two separate websites within IIS, and configure the bindings on each site - select the Bindings option and specify the correct hostname, for each site.

Note - this will only work for HTTP sites; if you want to route HTTPS to each site, they'll each need a unique IP address as you cannot setup hostname bindings for secure sites.

Comment: Yes this is what i want. But i don't want users to use ports like www.mydomain1.com:81 or www.mydomain2.com:82. I want users simple visit www.mydomain1.com or www.mydomain2.com and server understand automatically which port server configured to host this site.

Comment: You don't need to use ports to set up bindings - the server uses the hostname included in every HTTP request to route requests to the correct site.

Comment: Thank you Alan. I wasn't know that and my question is ugly know. Thank you for this simple and big information.